# PHP how to use/assign a DEFINED variable to a Class Member Variables directly?

Tags: php, oop

How do i use/assign a defined variable in my config file to a member variable of the class without using the constructor method like below

```
require('config.php');
class MyClass{

public $email=MY_EMAIL_FROM_CONFIG;

function MyClass(){

}
....

}
```

this direct assignment gives me a error, any other ways ? OR any explanation why this has been not allowed in PHP ?

Comment: I'd more than likely use a method which is available in all scopes. Perhaps look into the function: define()

Comment: Where do you get an error, and what does it say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**config.php**

```
define('EMAIL',  'some@email.com');
```

**MyClass.php**

```
require('config.php');
class MyClass{

    public $email= EMAIL;

    function myFunction(){

    }
    ....    
}
```

You might not need the constant to be assigned to a variable since it can be accessed anywhere within the class

Answer (score 0):

code-jaff has the correct solution. I have another one (almost the same).

**config.php**

```
$_CONFIG = Array(
 "email" => "myemail@example.com", 
 "host" => "example.com",
 ...
);
define("CONFIG", $_CONFIG);
```

**myclass.php**

```
require('config.php');
class MyClass{

    public $email= CONFIG["email"];

    function myFunction(){ }
}
```